# "No assets to download" on Github Actions using Github CLI

Tags: github, github-actions, github-cli

#### Context

I'm trying to download a release **from a private repository** in my Github Actions workflow using Github CLI [gh release download](https://cli.github.com/manual/gh_release_download) command.

**Here is my workflow:**

```
name: Download Release Private Repo

on: [push, workflow_dispatch]

jobs:
  get-asset:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: List Releases
        run: gh release list --repo GuillaumeFalourd/formulas-training # private repo
        env:
          GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.ACCESS_TOKEN }}

      - name: Check release
        run: gh release view 2.13.3 --repo GuillaumeFalourd/formulas-training
        env:
          GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.ACCESS_TOKEN }}

      - name: Fetch latest release
        run: gh release download 2.13.3 --repo GuillaumeFalourd/formulas-training
        env:
          GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.ACCESS_TOKEN }}
```

#### Issue

I'm getting a `no assets to download` message error when I use the Github CLI command `gh release download` in my Github Actions workflow as shown above.

#### What I tried

I checked in previous steps that the release is present and it actually returns me the following data:

**List releases STEP**

```
Run gh release list --repo GuillaumeFalourd/formulas-training
2.13.3  Latest  2.13.3  2021-04-05T17:17:17Z
2.13.2      2.13.2  2021-04-05T17:15:10Z
2.13.1      2.13.1  2021-04-05T17:11:37Z
2.13.0      2.13.0  2021-04-04T22:57:09Z
2.12.2      2.12.2  2021-04-01T21:35:37Z
1.13.0      1.13.0  2021-02-24T16:26:33Z
...
```

**Check release STEP**

```
Run gh release view 2.13.3 --repo GuillaumeFalourd/formulas-training
title:  2.13.3
tag:    2.13.3
draft:  false
prerelease: false
author: GuillaumeFalourd
created:    2021-04-05T17:16:56Z
published:  2021-04-05T17:17:17Z
url:    https://github.com/GuillaumeFalourd/formulas-training/releases/tag/2.13.3
```

Moreover, I followed what has been explained in [that thread on the github cli repository](https://github.com/cli/cli/issues/2167) and got the same error.

#### Notes

- [The full workflow run with the error can be found here](https://github.com/GuillaumeFalourd/poc-github-actions/runs/4715655494?check_suite_focus=true)
- The secret I use as GITHUB_TOKEN environment variable is a `Personal Access Token` with all permissions enabled.
- The release **2.13.3** from this private repository seems ok as it has been downloaded using the Github API in the past successfully.
- I used [this workflow as reference](https://github.com/JanosGit/download-release-from-private-repo-test/blob/main/.github/workflows/download-release.yml) which seems to work fine.

#### Question

What is wrong with my implementation? Did I miss something?